# Object query parameters are not listed in the generated OpenAPI file

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, swagger-maven-plugin

I'm trying to list the object query parameters in an OpenAPI file generated by swagger-maven-plugin.  I have the following endpoint which contains two objects `RecargaCupoFilter` and `Pageable`, each object has its own parameters.

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/wallet/recharge", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
@ApiOperation(value = "Allow to query recharge history", produces = "application/json")
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and (#filter.username == authentication.name or hasAnyRole('ROLE_COORDINADOR_CUPO', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR'))")
@ApiPageable
public ResponseEntity<List<OperacionDTO>> consultarRecargas(RecargaCupoFilter filter, Pageable pageable) {
    pageable = PaginationUtil.ensurePageMaxSize(pageable);
    Page<OperacionDTO> page = cupoService.consultarRecargaCupo(filter, pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil
            .generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
}
```

When I try to generate an OpenAPI file I get the following:

```yaml
  /api/wallet/recharge:
    get:
      summary: "Allow to query recharge history"
      description: ""
      operationId: "BilleteraResource_consultarRecargas_GET"
      produces:
      - "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      parameters:
      - name: "filter"
        in: "query"
        required: true
      - name: "sort"
        in: "query"
        description: "Criterios de ordenamiento, con formato: propiedad(,asc|desc).\
          \ El orden por defecto es ascendente. Se soportan múltiples criterios de\
          \ ordenamiento."
        required: false
        type: "array"
        items:
          type: "string"
        collectionFormat: "multi"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
          schema:
            type: "array"
            items:
              $ref: "#/definitions/OperacionDTO"
```

I expect to have something like the file generated by SpringFox.

```yaml
  /api/wallet/recharge:
    get:
      tags:
        - billetera-resource
      summary: Allow to query recharge historyo
      operationId: consultarRecargasUsingGET
      produces:
        - application/json;charset=UTF-8
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: offset
          in: query
          required: false
          type: integer
          format: int64
        - name: pageNumber
          in: query
          required: false
          type: integer
          format: int32
        - name: pageSize
          in: query
          required: false
          type: integer
          format: int32
```

PS: I'm using swagger-maven-plugin because it generates the OpenAPI file in Maven build phase without execute the app.

Comment: You may need to annotate the parameters using [`@Parameter`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#parameter).

Comment: The @Parameter annotation of what package?

Comment: io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations

Comment: I did not find Parameter annotation instead I found ApiParameter annotation which does not work